# How to install Hibernate Tools in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, eclipse-plugin, hibernate-tools

What is the proper way to install Hibernate Tools in Eclipse as a plugin?
The [Hibernate site](http://www.hibernate.org/255.html) doesn't really give any instructions.

Looking at the Hibernate Tools binary `HibernateTools-3.2.4.Beta1-R200810311334.zip`, it appears that I can just unzip this in my eclipse directory. Do I just unzip it in my eclipse directory? This seems like a hacky was to install it.

Answer (score 165, accepted):

Well, most convenient and safest way is to use JBoss update site within Eclipse software updates (Help -> Software Updates... -> Add Site...):

[The latest stable release update site for JBoss Tools](http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/stable/)

There you can find Hibernate tools together with other handy JBoss plugins.

Comment: As of this writing, this fails for the latest Eclipse version (3.7, indigo) because the JBoss Tools in "stable" only work with Eclipse<=3.6 (you'll get all sorts of dependency conflicts). Here are the indigo installation instructions: http://www.jboss.org/tools/download/installation/update_3_3 . To sum that article you need to add http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/development/indigo/ as your update site and then from the list of available software just choose "Hibernate Tools" (for convenience, it appears multiple times in different locations, just choose one).

Comment: just to add on the above, after you enter the site, you will find "Hibernate Tools" under "JBoss Web and Java EE Development" / "JBoss Data Services"

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-install-hibernate-tools-in-eclipse-ide/ If anyone is still not able to do it !

Comment: If you have Eclipse Juno use this URL instead: http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/stable/juno/

Comment: This is not working for Eclipse Neon. The update site seems to be void.

Answer (score 36):

Find the stable version of the hibernate plugin (Zip or URL for auto update) in the below URL.
http://www.jboss.org/tools/download

Do not install everything though. You just need:

1. The entire **All JBoss Tools 3.2.0** section
2. Hibernate Tools (**HT**) from **Application Development**
3. **HT** from **Data Services**
4. **JBoss Maven Hibernate Configurator** from **Maven Support** and
5. **HT** from **Web and Java EE Development**

That's all!

In 2013, you will be probably using the latest versions of Eclipse and Hibernate. For Eclipse-4.2.2. and JBoss Tools 4.0 you need:

1. From the **Abridged JBoss Tools 4.0**, the **JBoss Hibenate Tools** section
2. Hibernate Tools (**HT**) from **Application Development**
3. **HT** from **JBoss Data Services**
4. **JBoss Maven Hibernate Configurator** from **Maven Support** and
5. **HT** from **Web and Java EE Development**

Then you are ready to go!

Comment: I have installed above but unable to see hibernate perspective in eclipse.

Comment: This posting is two years old. I will check it out again and let you know ASAP...

Comment: @JagdevSingh Try these setting Jagdev!

Comment: Yes, it's 2013 but I am still constrained to Indigo (Eclipse 3.7.2) and unfortunately despite following your updated instructions, it is still failing (see comment [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/351640/how-to-install-hibernate-tools-in-eclipse#comment28627459_12012984)). Any way to work around this?

Answer (score 14):

Instructions for Eclipse Indigo:

- *Help -> Install New Software*
- Click on *Add*. Location:  http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/stable/
- Inside *JBoss Web and Java EE Development* folder, select *Hibernate Tools*
- Click on *Next*

Once installed click on *Window -> Show View -> Others*. A new window pops up. Click on folder *Hibernate* and select *Hibernate Configurations* to setup a DB connection. It is possible to setup a new connection using an existing Hiberbate properties file or creating a JDBC connection.

Once setup your DB connection click on Ping to test everything is correct.

Lastly, click on the *Open HQL Editor* button (third button on the top Hibernate Configurations menu) to run a HQL query.

Comment: It's about a year later and for various reasons I am constrained to use Eclipse Indigo, so I was happy to find your Indigo-specific instructions (+1). However, as soon as I try to install it, I received the following error: `Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Hibernate Tools 3.7.0.Final-v20130717-0715-B84 (org.hibernate.eclipse.feature.feature.group 3.7.0.Final-v20130717-0715-B84)`. Any idea why or how to solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Hello Daniel. It has been a long time I dealt with Hibernate Tools and currently I'm my current task have not much to do with Hibernate. However, this answer is a summary of a longer post I wrote about how to configure Hibernate Tools. Maybe it can help http://blogs.igalia.com/dpino/2010/09/26/configure-hibernate-tools/

Comment: Thanks. I am giving up on Hibernate Tools for now (the hbm.xml to Java auto-generation is enough for the size of the project I'm currently working), but I will consult your link once I determine I need the extra automation provided by Hibernate Tools.

Comment: Indeed this methods works on Eclipse Neon. However, it installs a three year old version of Hibernate (3.7). Is there a way to install a more up to date version?

Comment: @LuísdeSousa I'm not longer a Java developer, so I don't really know. The recipe above installs JBossTools, right? It seems that JBossTools features several Hibernate runtimes, maybe 3.7 is the default. Try to switch your Hibernate runtime version and that may update Hibernate Tools. But I don't really know, that's only a guess. https://tools.jboss.org/features/hibernate.html

Answer (score 6):

## Installing Hibernate Tools on Eclipse Neon (4.6)

Go to the menu `Help` > `Install New Software` and click the `Add` button.

Use something like *JBoss Hibernate* for the name and insert the following URL for the location:

```
http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/neon/stable/updates/
```

Wait for the product tree to load and then expand the `JBoss Web and Java EE Development` folder and select the `Hibernate Tools` product and click the `Next >` button. Then follow on accepting all the subsequent questions, licence, etc.

When the installation is finished, restart Eclipse as required. After that, to open the Hibernate perspective go to the menu `Window` > `Perspective` > `Open Perspective` > `Others` and search for *Hibernate*.

Answer (score 4):

Step-by-step tutorial :

http://shivasoft.in/blog/sql/myqsl/step-by-step-hibernate-tutorial-using-eclipse-wtp/

Reverse Engineering Approach :

http://www.wikihow.com/Generate-Hibernate-Pojo-Classes-from-DB-Tables

Answer (score 3):

Since it is for Ganymede (eclipse 3.4), I would advise to uncompress the zip in the **dropins** in the HibernateTools-3.2.4.Beta1-R20081031133 directory created after the name of the archive.

Once it is done, create in the `[eclipse\dropins\HibernateTools-3.2.4.Beta1-R20081031133]` an 'eclipse' directory, in which you will move the plugins and features directories creating at the extraction of the files of the archive.

Add a .exclipseextension in `[eclipse\dropins\HibernateTools-3.2.4.Beta1-R20081031133\eclipse]`:

```
name=QuickRex
id=org.hibernate.eclipse
version=3.2.4b1
```

So:

```
eclipse
    dropins
         HibernateTools-3.2.4.Beta1-R20081031133
             eclipse
                 .eclipseextension
                 features
                 plugins
```

Relaunch eclipse and the plugin Hibernate should be detected.

If you install another eclipse, just copy the content of your dropins directory to the new `eclipse\dropins` and your set of plugins will be detected again.

Answer (score 3):

### Method-1 Online Hibernate Tool Installation

---

In Eclipse IDE, menu bar, select **Help** >> **Install New Software …** put the Eclipse update site URL "download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/stable/**`Eclipse_Version`**”

[image: Eclipse Install New Software - Hibernate]

Select the tool and click on **Next**. Do not select all the tools; it will install all the unnecessary tools. We just need hibernate tools.

Accept licence agreement and click finish.It will take some minutes to complete installation process.

[image: Installation Process]

After installation, restart the eclipse to verify whether Hibernate tools is installed properly,we will look at Hibernate Perspective in Eclipse->>Window->>Open Perspective->>Other

### Method-2 Offline Installation

---

If you don’t have the internet connection and want the offline method to add hibernate tools in eclipse. To install the Hibernate Tools, extract the `HibernateTools-5.X.zip` file and move all the files inside the features folder into the features folder of the eclipse installation directory and move all the files inside the plugins folder into the plugins folder of the ecilpse installation directory.

After restart, Go to **Eclipse->>Window->>Open Perspective->>Other**, the following dialog box appears, select Hibernate and click the **Ok** button.

[image: Check Eclipse Perspective]

That’s it . We successfully installed JBoss Hibernate Tools in Eclipse. :) now Happy Coding

**References :**

- http://www.jboss.org/tools/download
- http://www.jboss.org/tools/download/installation

Comment: Method 1 fails with Eclipse Neon.

Comment: @LuísdeSousa try with second method.

Answer (score 2):

Menu Help > Install new software

Use this url : http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/stable/

Comment: This will try (and fail) to install an outdated version: 3.4.

Answer (score 2):

I'm running Eclipse Indigo 64 bit on Windows 7 64 bit and I kept getting missing dependency errors associated with Maven and other plugins using the JBoss Tools 3.3.X latest download.  Here is the [link](https://www.jboss.org/tools).

So, I opted to only install Hibernate Tools with nothing else by typing in "hibernate" at the top of the install software dialog in eclipse.  Only 4 items showed up, so that is all I installed.  It worked fine with no problems.  Here is the [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-install-hibernate-tools-in-eclipse-ide/) that I used to get it installed properly after several failed attempts.

I don't know if part of this was due to having a lot of plugins already installed or if this is the best solution or not, but I thought I'd share it with everyone.

Comment: Same thing here (see [earlier comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/351640/how-to-install-hibernate-tools-in-eclipse#comment28626899_13045851)). I typed `hibernate` in the "filter" line but I get more than 4 items... I actually get 6 of them (including "JBoss Maven Hibernate Configurator"). I am going to try selecting all of them now and see what happens... Thanks +1 for now.

Comment: Unfortunately it still fails. This time with `Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: JBoss Maven Hibernate Configurator 1.5.0.Final-v20130719-2050-B70 (org.jboss.tools.maven.hibernate.feature.feature.group 1.5.0.Final-v20130719-2050-B70)`.

Comment: That error shows up for Eclipse Kepler.  See http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/error/report/1196126  Are you using Eclipse Indigo?

Answer (score 1):

uncompress the zip  HibernateTools-3.2.4.Beta1-R20081031133
later in eclipse
 --> menu Help -> Update Sofwate -> add site -> local add, and select de folder uncompress an install automatic

Answer (score 1):

> I can't for the life of me get the Next or Finish button to not go grey

This is the eclipse pain in the ass UI. If you unckecked previously some components because they have broken dependencies, it blocks in the license. You have to unselect them in the first step.

Note that avoid to use the update feature of Eclipse it broke all my plugin, I had to delete my ./eclipse folder and reinstall all.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have copied the plugins and features folder to eclipse (eg. c:\program files\eclipse (or whereever you installed it). You will see a features and plugins folder there already) you can check if hibernate has installed by going to Help > Software updates > installed software. If hibernate is not listed close eclipse and launch it again via a command window with this command "eclipse -clean".

Answer (score -3):

For Eclipse plugins, you just unzip them and drop the folder in the Eclipse\Plugins directory. Simple as that.

Comment: I did that. It didn't work. The plug-in seems to install correctly, but it has trouble finding my project classes. I think this is due to some extra settings of how the plug-ins see each other, which are not applied automatically with the manual install.