# Generate schema from entities using JPA2 + Hibernate + Eclipse 4.2 + MySQL 5.5

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa-2.0, ddl

I am new to Hibernate/JPA and I am stuck at what I think is the last step.
I have created a schema in my MySQL instance and want to generate the tables for the schema from the JPA entities I have created. 
I get an option in JPA Tools in eclipse "Generate Tables from Entities" but that gives me a message "Generate Tables from Entities is not supported by the Generic Platform. 
Is there a plugin or tool I need to use to make this work ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using hibernate you can:

- set "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" in your project to one of following values "update | create | create-drop" (read more at: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html). Schema will be created/updated when you run your application.
- you can try Hibernate 3 Maven plugin, check hbm2ddl goal ( http://mojo.codehaus.org/maven-hibernate3/hibernate3-maven-plugin/)

Comment: I installed Hibernate Tools and tried using it on my Eclipse project. It seems that Eclipse 4.2 is not compatible with the tool and it crashed my project. I am wondering if I would need to try it with an older version of Eclipse. It seems that this solution answers my question though. Thank you.

Answer (score 18):

You will need to first install Hibernate Tools - [How to install Hibernate Tools in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351640/how-to-install-hibernate-tools-in-eclipse)

Then go to Project->Preferences->JPA and change the Platform to the appropriate version of Hibernate instead of the Generic Platform.