# how to create hbm.xml file in eclipse

Tags: hibernate

how to create hbm.xm file for a noramal Java Bean class in eclipse
Ex:
I have a table SampleUser Table is there,for that table i need pojo class & hbm file
can we create manually that above two files??
or
Is there any way to create these(Pojo & hbm.xml file) without using any Hibernate Tool??

Comment: Yes, you can create it manually. This is a simple example of an hbm : http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-component-mapping-example/

Comment: This may be useful to you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/351640/how-to-install-hibernate-tools-in-eclipse

Answer (score 0):

You can create them manually, as long as the syntax is correct. 
You can check Hibernate [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/), specifically the [mapping chapter](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you install RedHat CodeReady Studio from Marketplace there is a wizard to create the hbm.xml automatically