# Hibernate Prespective doesn't showup in Luna even after Installation of Hibernate Eclipse Plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, jboss

Installed Hibernate Plugin [http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/stable/luna/] in Eclipse Luna 4.4.1 but after installation couldn't able to locate the Hibernate prespective (prespective suppose to show after installation).

I also tried the alternate way of installing the Hibernate Eclipse Plugin.Downloaded the zip from  [http://tools.jboss.org/downloads/jbosstools/luna/4.2.2.Final.html#zips] and copied the plugin/features content to Eclipse directories plugin/features.

In my both approach of Installation, Hibernate Eclipse Plugin is installed which I  could confirm by  locating it at Help->Installation Details->Installation Software but couldn't locate the Hibernate prespective in Eclipse.

Note : The issue was only with Eclipse Luna. Had no problems with previous versions of Eclipse.

For your information tried 4.2.2.Final as well as 4.2.1.Final. Both didn't bring any Hibernate Prespective in Eclipse Luna. Plz do Share your views if have any problems with Hibernate Prespective in Luna

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems a *bug*. A brazilian user has reported the same problem. See: http://www.guj.com.br/46522-eclipse-nao-apresenta-perspectiva-do-hibernate:

> (...) estou trabalhando em um projeto com implementação do hibernate, meu servidor de aplicação é o Jboss e o eclipse é o Luna. (...) Mas, meu eclipse não apresenta esta perspectiva, já copiei a pasta do eclipse dos outros programadores onde a funcionalidade e funciona perfeitamente, mas quando abro o eclipse na minha maquina, não aparece a bendita.
>
> Não faço ideia de como fazer pra resolver esse problema (...)

I suggested him to open an issue on project's official website:: https://jira.jboss.org/jira/browse/JBIDE/issues

PS: Another user has commented in the [How to install Hibernate Tools in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351640/how-to-install-hibernate-tools-in-eclipse#comment22524760_5974426):

> I have installed above but unable to see hibernate perspective in eclipse. –  Jagdev Singh Apr 5 '13 at 11:21

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse

Window > Open Perspective > Other... > Hibernate?

Comment: That's where I couldn't find the Hibernate option and that's my question all about

Comment: Alan, Thx for quick post on this. The issue was only with Luna and it still persists