# Which eclipse is suitable for Java SE, Java EE and Hibernate?

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate

I am new to java. Can anyone suggest me which eclipse is suitable for Java SE, Java EE and Hibernate development?

**Note:** I am using Linux machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Eclipse Kepler](http://eclipse.org/kepler/)

> In computer programming, Eclipse is an integrated development
>   environment (IDE). It contains a base workspace and an extensible
>   plug-in system for customizing the environment. Written mostly in
>   Java, Eclipse can be used to develop applications. By means of various
>   plug-ins, Eclipse may also be used to develop applications in other
>   programming languages: Ada, ABAP, C, C++, COBOL, Fortran, Haskell,
>   JavaScript, Lasso, Lua, Natural, Perl, PHP, Prolog, Python, R, Ruby
>   (including Ruby on Rails framework), Scala, Clojure, Groovy, Scheme,
>   and Erlang.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse for Java EE development will be a good choice.

http://eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/lunasr2

Answer (score 1):

Use [Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers](https://eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/lunasr2)

You will find
[Linux 32b version download](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/luna/SR2/eclipse-jee-luna-SR2-linux-gtk.tar.gz)
[Linux 64b version download](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/luna/SR2/eclipse-java-luna-SR2-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz)

To install [Hibernate tools](https://www.google.es/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCEQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fhibernate.org%2Ftools%2F&ei=I_gkVfvqOYPuaqn0gJgM&usg=AFQjCNHOzIgqE4dPoHV3uQsRf-y77PKmXw&sig2=t3dDAEYFB1WRuJ6azBjUgg&bvm=bv.90237346,d.d24) visit [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351640/how-to-install-hibernate-tools-in-eclipse)