# No more tabs in Properties File Editor

Tags: eclipse, properties-file, resourcebundle

I am using Eclipse Neon.3 (4.6.3). In the past, Eclipse used to have several tabs on the bottom of the editor window, when a file was opened in the *Properties File Editor* mode. There you could choose to view the file either in a table-like view or as a plain text file.

I usually edit my resource files in plain text, which still works fine. However, the table view had one nice feature: Duplicate entries were highlighted in red color in the table-view.

But this view is no longer available, since there are no tabs in the *Properties File Editor* anymore. Did I miss anything? Where has this tab gone? Do I need an additional plug-in for this feature? As far as I can tell, this used to be a built-in feature of Eclipse.

Comment: Maybe you have used the [MultiProperties plug-in](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/multiproperties#group-screenshots) in the past?

Comment: Thank you, but no. Meanwhile, I found out that the feature was provided by Red Hat's **JBoss Tools Properties Editor**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I still had an old installation of Eclipse Mars and found out, that the feature in question is not built-in to Eclipse. The feature is provided by the [JBoss Tools Properties Editor](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_Developer_Studio/6.0/html/Hibernate_Tools_Reference_Guide/properties_editor.html), which is part of Red Hat's **Hibernate Tools**.

[image: JBoss Properties Editor]

To install on Eclipse Mars, follow the instructions of [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41742879/1438038).