# Hibernate auto code-generator from db schema

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, jboss, hibernate-tools

I'm trying to auto generate class codes with annotation from existing db (mySql). 
I have problem with configuration hibernate tools in eclipse this way to dont map foregin ID-key to int but to class.

Eg, I have entity A with ID indicates to entity B (ofc integer), when I use auto generete that tool maps to int, not to class.

How to configure this tool to achive what i mention above?

Thanks,

Comment: Without knowing what 'issue' you are facing, no one can help you.

Comment: @Sundaraj Govindasany Sorry, I misspoked. I dont have specific 'issue' with configuration, I just dont know how to do this exacly.                                                                          By default it map foreign key for int, not for class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install Hibernate Tools in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351640/how-to-install-hibernate-tools-in-eclipse)